# Get correct dimensions of window Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

my phone's screen height is 800px. when I do this:

```
var windowSize = $(window).height();
alert(windowSize);
```

it says that it's only 508px;

I'm using jQuery Mobile, not sure if this has an impact on screen dimensions.

what would be the best was to get the correct height of phone screens?

Comment: Perhaps the browser and other navigational elements are taking up space?

Comment: Why do you need to find out the full height of the screen when you're probably constrained to the client area of the browser? If you're looking for the workable area, you already have the correct answer. If you're trying to do some sort of hardware/feature detection, you might be better off sniffing the user agent header. Or try CSS media queries?

Comment: what about `window.outerHeight`?

Comment: @kpsuperplane I just tried a blank page with the script on it and it still gave me 508. I was wondering if it could be the viewport in the META <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height ,initial-scale=1" />

Comment: @AtesGoral I'm compiling a quick PhoneGap app with jQuery Mobile and I'm trying to make all of the elements fit on the screen of every device nicely. I figured if I got the dimensions of the device and applied it to the CSS it would work nicely but it seems like there are issues because sometimes the page is too big and you can scroll up and down on it

Comment: @MarshallHouse gonna try that now

Comment: @MarshallHouse tried it and came back with the same outcome of 508 =(

Comment: well that's all Apple wanted you to have then.

Comment: Im working on Android (Samsung Galaxy S2)

Comment: ah, just kind of figured Apple for such a thing. How do you know the screen is 800px? My desktop is 768px...

Comment: try `screen.height` - last call.

Comment: @MarshallHouse maybe I'm doing this wrong then. I looked up by specs and it says 800x480 so I assumed pixels. All I'm trying to do is find the exact height and width and apply it to the body to make it static on all devices so that there's now scrolling on the phone, whats the best way to go upon doing this?

Comment: All you have is what the browser gives you. But if that is the case, if your browser is saying 508 - then tha's how much room you have to work with. even if the screen is 800px, it's not available. so you can rely on `$(window).height()` for what you want. why don't you just make a black div as tall as the return value and see how much of the screen it uses?

Comment: @MarshallHouse i got it to return the correct height using screen.height thank you so much, submit it as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
screen.height
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_screen.asp